# Vulkan spec clarification regarding subpass dependency

Tags: vulkan

I need some clarity about something in the Vulkan Spec. Section 8.1 says:

> Render passes must include subpass dependencies (either directly or
> via a subpass dependency chain) between any two subpasses that operate
> on the same attachment or aliasing attachments and those subpass
> dependencies must include execution and memory dependencies separating
> uses of the aliases, if at least one of those subpasses writes to one
> of the aliases. These dependencies must not include the
> VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT if the aliases are views of distinct image
> subresources which overlap in memory.

Does this mean that if subpass S0 write to attachment X (either as Color, Depth, or Resolve) and subsequent subpass S1 uses that attachment X (either as Color, Input, Depth, or Resolve), then there must be a subpass dependency from S0->S1 (directly or via chain)?

EDIT 1:
Upon further thinking, the scenario is not just if S0 writes and S1 reads. If S0 reads and S1 writes, that also needs synchronization from S0->S1.

EDIT 2:
I should say that what I was specifically unsure before was with a color attachment that is written by 2 different subpasses. Assuming that subpasses don't  have a logical dependency, other than they use the same color attachment, they could be ran in parallel if they used different attachments. Before reading this paragraph, I was under the impression that dependencies were only needed between 2 subpasses if subpass B need some actual data from subpass A, and so needed to wait until this data was available. That paragraphs talks about general memory hazards.

If there is no logical need for 2 subpasses to be ordered in a certain way, the GPU could decide which is the better one to run first. But, if the developer always has to declare dependencies if 2 subpasses touch the same attachment, then that's potential speed lost that only gpu could figure out. It shouldn't be hard for the GPU to figure out that, although 2 subpasses don't have a developer-stated dependency between them, they do read/write to the same attachment, so it shouldn't just mindlessly write to it at the same time from both subpasses. Yes, I mean that the GPU would do some simple synchronization for basic cases, so as to not decapitate itself.

Comment: Generally you need to explicitly synchronize everything in Vulkan. Letting driver do something that requires magic is antithesis to Vulkan. Driver could perhaps figure it out, but the figuring out itself requires inspection of the workload which costs performance. Vulkan discourages drivers to be too smart for their benefit and just do what they are told. I am not exactly clear by your question. I suggest instead piling on it to instead reform the question to the best form it can have. If anyone wants to see the edit history, they can without you writing "EDIT" everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a render pass that has two subpasses A and B, and both use the same attachment, and A writes to the shared attachment, then there is *logically* an ordering requirement between A and B. There has to be.

If there is no ordering requirement between two operations, then it is logically OK for those two operations to be *interleaved*. That is, partially running one, then partially running another, then completing the first. And they can be interleaved to *any* degree.

You can't interleave A and B, because the result you get is incoherent. For any shared attachment between A and B, if B writes to a pixel in that attachment, should A read that data? What if B writes twice to it? Should A read the pre-written value, the value after the first write, or the value after the second write? If A also writes to that pixel, should B's write happen before it or after? Or should A's write be between two of B's writes? And if so, which ones?

Interleaving A and B just doesn't make sense. There must be a logical order between them. So the scenario you hypothesize, where there "is no logical need for 2 subpasses to be ordered in a certain way" does not make sense.

Either you want any reads/writes done by B to happen before the writes done by A, or you want them to happen after. Neither choice is better or more correct than the other; they are both equally valid usage patterns.

Vulkan is an *explicit*, low-level rendering API. It is not Vulkan's job to figure out what you're trying to do. It's your job to *tell* Vulkan what you want it to do. And since either possibility is perfectly valid, you must tell Vulkan what you want done.

---

> Both A & B need 5 color attachments each, but other than the memory, they don't care about each other. Why can't the GPU share the 5 color attachments intelligently between the subpasses, interleaving as it sees fit?

How would that *possibly* work?

If the first half of A writes some data to attachments that the second half of A's operations will read that data, B can't get in the middle of that and overwrite that data. Because then the data will be overwritten with incorrect values and the second half of A won't have access to the data written by the first half.

If A and B both start with clearing buffers (FYI: calling `vkCmdClearAttachments` at all should be considered at least potentially dubious), then no interleaving is possible. since they first thing they will do is overwrite the attachments *in their entirety*. The rendering commands within those subpasses expect the attachments to have known data, and having someone come along and mess with it will break those assumptions and yield incorrect results.

Therefore, whatever these subpasses are doing, they *must* execute in their entirety before the other. You may not care what order they execute in, but they must entirely execute in *some order*, with no overlap between them.

Vulkan just makes you spell out what that order is.

Comment: There is no logical ordering. It's just 2 subpasses trying to save memory by reusing image buffers. Maybe there are 3 subpasses, A, B, and C, where A & B would need to synchronize with C, but not with each-other. Both A & B need 5 color attachments each, but other than the memory, they don't care about each other. Why can't the GPU share the 5 color attachments intelligently between the subpasses, interleaving as it sees fit? If the developer has to state the dependencies, then it's basically: B must wait on all attachments that A uses, or vice versa.

Comment: @Dess: "*There is no logical ordering. It's just 2 subpasses trying to save memory by reusing image buffers.*" You can't save memory by having the two stomp on each other's data. There must be ***an*** order, even if you don't care what that order is. One must complete *in its entirety* before another. That's what establishing an order means.

Comment: @Dess: I've updated the answer with specific information about your comment.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you that an order is needed. I'm saying that this order could easily be figured out by the gpu, in cases like this, and that the gpu would do a better job than the developer. My understanding is that Vulkan isn't just inflexible for the sake of it; it's supposed to be for speed reason. This would be an example where it would be faster and easier for devs. I'm not saying that dependencies aren't needed at all, just that it's not unresonable to assume that the api would handle straight forward cases like this.

Comment: @Dess: First, these cases basically don't happen. People just don't render this way. Second, "*it would be faster*" is a statement that would need evidence behind it. I see no reason why a GPU would prefer one order over another. And third, if a particular GPU did prefer one order over another, you can always profile for that specific GPU and adjust your subpass ordering as needed.

Comment: Ok, I give up. I feel like I'm going from a discussion to an argument. The answer I was looking for was, basically, whether color->color and resolve->resolve dependency was necessary, and it is. So, I'm good. Thanks man.